# Why are there artifacts when using two point clouds together in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use two or more point clouds, but it just does not work - there are colr/transparency artifacts. How to fix, please?

My code so far looks like this:

```
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry ();
            ...
            var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial ({
                var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial ({
                size: 60,
                //size: 20, sizeAttenuation: false,
                map: texture,
                vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, transparent: true
            });

            var particles = new THREE.PointCloud (geometry, material);

            particles.sortParticles = true;
```

Try it live at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rajedero/1/)

Comment: nothing but depthWrite: false helps... oh well.

Comment: "This bin was created anonymously and its free preview has expired."... jsfiddle please? :)

Comment: ...or you could click "dismiss" and "run with js". here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKuxL/ if this kind of stuff cannot work with depthWrite, why not turn it off by default?

Comment: Cleaned up the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKuxL/1/. This has nothing to do with "two" PointClouds... I think the best you can do is `alphaTest = 0.5`. That solves the transparency issue. The overlapping sprites makes proper rendering impossible, I think... You can change the blending mode, however.... Maybe @mrdoob has an idea...

Comment: @WestLangley but when I have just one point cloud, there is no problem

Comment: @makc WebGLRenderer does not sort elements between different pointclouds. It only sorts objects and elements inside the object if you enable that.